# Reference element in <label for> with ember.js

Tags: for-loop, ember.js, label

in my ember app I'm looking for a way to reference an element in `<label for>` that works within an `{{#each}}`-Block. Example:

```
{{@each}
  ...
  {{view "radio-button" name="options" selectionBinding="options" value="1"}}
  <label for="???">Option 1</label>

  {{view "radio-button" name="options" selectionBinding="options" value="2"}}
  <label for="???">Option 2</label>
  ...
{{/each}}
```

Searching the net I found several solutions, but none works within `{{#each}}`. What is the recommended way to do this?

Thanks in advance.
Dirk

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by giving each `radio-button` a `viewName`.

```
{{view "radio-button" name="options" selectionBinding="options" value="1" viewName="option1"}}
<label {{bind-attr for="view.option1.elementId"}}>Option 1</label>
```

See http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xokurixucapi/1/edit for an example.

Just saw that you actually want it to work in a loop. You can try to bind the `viewName` to the loop index, did you have a look at [this](http://mozmonkey.com/2014/03/ember-getting-the-index-in-each-loops/)?

Comment: Another problem with this solution is that it no longer works with ember.js 1.7.0. Perhaps a bug. If so, it is a good idea to add the loop index once it is fixed.